# ingress controller with Kubernetes cluster 1.20

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have installed Kubernetes cluster 1.20
I am trying to use install nginx ingress controller
but according Kubernetes's doc

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

it is stable for  v1.19 .
does it work with versin 1.20 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works with k8s version 1.19 + with API version networking.k8s.io/v1. It is a stable feature from kubernetes version 1.19